# PHP: Compare 2 arrays and get the occurrence range

Tags: php

I have a bigger array with all numbers as [8,2,3,7,4,6,5,1,9], then I have a smaller array which is
a subset of the bigger array such as [6,3,7]. How can I get the occurrence range for the smaller array in the bigger array? The expected result should be 2 to 5.

Comment: I certainly googled and can't solve this. The reason I try is obviously I need this function to find the range frequencies so I have an idea of the distributions for the smaller arrays in the bigger array.

Comment: What is an "occurrence range"? Is the result here supposed to be "2 to 5" because the "left-most" number it finds is 3 at position 2, and the right-most is 6 at position 5 - is that what you mean?

Comment: @CBroe, exactly. the 7 doesn't matter because it's in the middle

Comment: Can all numbers occur only once? Then you just need to loop over your subset, use `array_search` to find the first occurrence of the current number - and determine the minimum and maximum of the positions you found. If they can appear multiple times, then you want to find the first and the last occurrence, separately - the latter can easily be done by using searching the reversed array.

Comment: @CBroe, Yes only occur once. I haven't tried array_search cause the real data are much bigger both for the smaller and the bigger array. I thought there would be an easier way I just missed.

Answer (score 0):

> array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful

You can read more on [PHP:array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

You can use array_search to find first corresponding in the array

Now using simple foreach we can find maximum occurrence and the minimum one

Let's create a function to do this favor for us

```php
$array = [8,2,3,7,4,6,5,1,9];
$subset = [6,3,7];

function get_occurrence_range($array, $subset)
{
    $min = sizeof($array);
    $max = 0;
    
    foreach($subset as $value) {
        $occurrence = array_search($value, $array);
        $min = min($min, $occurrence);
        $max = max($max, $occurrence);
    }
    
    return [$min, $max];
}


$range = get_occurrence_range($array, $subset); // result as an array -> [2, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want and it worked!

Comment: I'm a fan of `min`/`max` for stuff like this, saves the "extensive" if statements. `$min = min($min, $occurrence);` and `$max = max($max, $occurrence);`

Comment: That's a good idea. it is more readable . I have updated the post.